# Is it ok to pass react setState hook to 3rd party library class instance?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, use-state, expo-av

I am writing player UI in react-native with expo. There is a 3rd party library `expo-av`. And in examples section of that lib, react component initialize instance of `mediaObject` in `useEffect`  and saves reference to it in ref (`useRef`). And handle events from mediaObject directly in react component via `mediaObjectRef.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate = status => {}`

I wrote a Class `Media`, that wraps `mediaObject` and put there all logic about playing. And also on init() i pass react players' setState hook to this class. And there from onPlaybackStatusUpdate method I update react UI component. Is it normal? I can't find about this approach in google.

I avoid to put this logic to component, because I need to extend my Media class into MediaAdvanced with more logic, and rewrite there event handlers.

Comment: `setState` isn't a react hook. If you are referring to the state updater returned then yes, you *could* pass this around to other components to call, but then you leave it to other components to maintain your state invariant. Better to instead pass a callback around that the player component defines, this way the player component maintains control.

Comment: yes, I mean [state, setState] = useState() . But I pass it not to other component, but to class instance that wraps 3rd party library (not react component, just some player.mediaObject instanse )

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we've a clearer idea what you are referring to.

Comment: It is not bug report. It is just theoretical question: Is it ok or not: to send `setState` to class instance (not react component, just some custom OOP class instance).
And it is hard to extract minimal code.